# Wordpress Static going to HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a WordPress server inside a docker container. WordPress is running with a nginx server inside. When I go through the initial installation phase, css (and other files) worked perfectly. But the when I load the main site, those resources redirected to HTTP://example.com/blogs/... instead of HTTPS.

Here are the URLs from the inspect:

```
https://example.com/blogs/
http://example.com/blogs/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.1.1
```

Here are my Nginx configuration from example.com:

```
location /blogs/ {
                proxy_pass HTTP://localhost:8080/;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_read_timeout 1800s;
        }
```

I have updated the wp-config.php file with the following information

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com/blogs/');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com/blogs/');
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/blogs' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Please let me know if u need any more information.

--- update #1 ---

Nginx Server block

```
server {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name example.com; # managed by Certbot
       
        location /blogs/ {
                proxy_pass HTTP://localhost:8080/;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_read_timeout 1800s;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # :managed by Certbot
    if ($scheme != https) {
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: How does your server block in nginx look like?

Comment: I have the nginx block on the question description.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nginx ssl reverse proxy for wordpress docker wont load resources and css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70726914/nginx-ssl-reverse-proxy-for-wordpress-docker-wont-load-resources-and-css)

Answer (score 0):

Check in the wp_options table if `siteurl` and `home` are also set with https.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a server block for your domain, make sure you have these lines in your server block to redirect all non-https request to https:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
the rest of your code
        if ($scheme != https) {
            return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
the rest of your code
    }
```

Comment: I have updated nginx server block on my question description. Bt the problem remains.

Comment: try replacing `server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }` with `if ($scheme != https) {
            return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;`
and a simple restart of nginx, `systemctl restart nginx`

Comment: Issue persists after changes.