# nginx ssl reverse proxy for wordpress docker wont load resources and css

Tags: docker, nginx-reverse-proxy

recently i configured wordpress site with docker and it runs on port 8080 and then i configured nginx reverse proxy on host and it was totally fine.. but sooner after i added ssl site wont load itz css and i can not find the error

```
    server {
  server_name mysite.com; # change this

  # global gzip on
#  gzip on;
#  gzip_min_length 10240;
#  gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
#  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

 # add_header Cache-Control public;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080; # change this
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffers 12 12k;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = mysite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  server_name mysite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Got same error here. Any fix?

Comment: Got https://www.aiprose.com/blog/148 might help

Answer (score 3):

List your docker containers to get your instance name

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

Access the wp-config.php on docker instance.

```
# Access your instance files 
sudo docker exec -i -t instance_name bash

# Install nano to edit files
apt install nano

nano wp-config.php
```

Add following at top of wp-config.php

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false){
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
}
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
}
```

Add following at end of wp-config.php. Repalce example.com with your domain name

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://exampe.com/');
```

In your nginx file ie /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com, Ensure you have added `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;`

```
server {

    root /var/www/example.com;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mazclan.otherside.co.ke/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mazclan.otherside.co.ke/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.mazclan.otherside.co.ke) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mazclan.otherside.co.ke) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



    server_name mazclan.otherside.co.ke www.mazclan.otherside.co.ke;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

Now restart you docker instance

```
sudo docker restart instance_name
```